# Python Merge Dictionary from Mysql Results

Tags: python, mysql, dictionary

I am trying to take the outputs of 7 MySQL queries and merge them on a specific field (the first, ID).

My first initial thought was to take the results of the seven queries and put them into Dictionaries with the first field as the KEY and then the rest as the VALUES.

```
returnDict = dict([(k[0], k[1:]) for k in output])
```

Once I get the results from the seven queries into their own Dicts I can combine them into one dictionary by doing the following:

```
for d in (firstDict, secondDict, thirdDict, fourthDict, fifthDict, sixthDict, seventhDict): 
            for key, value in d.iteritems():
                    dd[key].append(value)
```

Now, the only problem I having is when the above code combines the dictionary it does not "break apart" the original dictionaries, it only appends them, thus creating a fairly messy dictionary.

This is what it looks like:

```
6: ('blah.net', datetime.datetime(2011, 6, 23, 0, 0), 4L, 1L, datetime.datetime(2011, 6, 23, 0, 0)), ('Foo', 1L), ('Unknown Foo', 2L), (datetime.datetime(2013, 11, 14, 12, 30, 24), 'ORIGINAL CATEGORY 3')
```

This is what I want it to look like:

```
6: 'blah.net', datetime.datetime(2011, 6, 23, 0, 0), 4L, 1L, datetime.datetime(2011, 6, 23, 0, 0), 'Foo', 1L, 'Unknown Foo', 2L, datetime.datetime(2013, 11, 14, 12, 30, 24), 'ORIGINAL CATEGORY 3'
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution involves using a union query on the database side.

If you want to do this in Python, I would do something like

```
from collections import defaultdict
dd = defaultdict(list)
for d in (firstDict, secondDict, ...):
    for key, value in d.items():
        dd[key].append(value)
```

Comment: I think a MySQL Union requires every SELECT query result to have the same number of returned columns and only removes duplicates, right?

Also -- your above code is nearly exactly what I am currently doing.